# rdd.toDF() changes float to None

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

(Using Apache Spark 1.6.0)
Hi all,

I have a `SparseVector` (which is basically defined by two numpy arrays namely `values` and `indices`.
I want to get the highest values and their indices, to do it I use:

```
r = df.map(lambda row: Row(**dict(row.asDict(), top=f(vec)))))
```

where the f function returns `[ [sorted_indices], [sorted_values] ]` the following way:

```
def f(v):
    m, i = zip(*sorted(zip(v.values, v.indices), reverse=True))
    m = [ float(j) for j in m]
    i = [ int(j) for j in i]
    return [i, m]
```

At that point `r` is a `pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD` and I can check my values are ok using, for example.

```
r.first().top[1]
```

The problem comes when I try to get a `DataFrame` using:

```
df2 = r.toDF()
```

Then my values are only `None`, i.e.

```
df2.first().top[1] # i.e. the highest values of the first Vector
```

shows `None`.

So, it really looks like the `toDF()` function destroys my data. This would be quite odd if Spark cannot handle builtin float type.

Any ideas?
thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because types don't match. If you take a look at the types you'll see that `top` column is represented as `array<array<bigint>>` while values should be `array<float>`. You function should an object that can be converted to a `struct` column `struct<array<bigint>, array<float>>`. An obvious choice is either a `tuple` or a `Row`:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

def f(v):
    m, i = zip(*sorted(zip(v.values, v.indices), reverse=True))
    m = [ float(j) for j in m]
    i = [ int(j) for j in i]
    return Row(indices=i, values=m)
```

Also if vector is already in a `DataFrame` is better to use an UDF here:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = StructType([
    StructField("indices", ArrayType(IntegerType())), 
    StructField("values",  ArrayType(DoubleType()))
])

df.withColumn("top", udf(f, schema)(col("vec_column")))
```